# How to implement injection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, code-injection

I need to be able to use this call:

```
h = x.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.one] = b.two; a}
```

Where x is a sequence of Couple objects (these just contain two number fields, one and two).

I am not sure how to implement the inject method in Couple.

Comment: Yeah, what is 'x', also what result are you looking to get.  2 or three x values with results would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using injection in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416142/using-injection-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `#each` method in `Couple`, then include `Enumerable` in it.

```
class Couple
  def each
    yield "a"
    yield "b"
  end

  include Enumerable
end

couple = Couple.new
couple.inject("") { |str, obj| str + obj }
# => "ab"
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html

Comment: OOC - would that "each" work? would it ever get to `yield 'b'` ?

Comment: Yes, you can call yield repeatedly with different arguments.

Comment: cool :) For some reason I thought it would return at the first yield.

Comment: I get "undefined method inject"

Comment: And you included Enumerable? Enumerable provides inject. Post your code.