# Using injection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a class called Hsh which basically simulates a hash. It has an array of Couple objects (which hold fields named one and two, one is an int another is a string name of that int).

I am supposed to be able to accept the following call:

```
h = x.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.one] = b.two; a}
```

Where x is the Hsh object.

I am not sure how to implement the inject method within Hsh? Like, what would I write in:

```
def inject ????
??
??
end
```

All it's supposed to do is create a hash map.

Comment: Not possible...it is a duplicate. People stopped trying to answer that one.

Comment: @antonpug, please delete the other question or this one, or we can vote to close one or the other. Currently this one has the most votes, and the most answers, so the other one is the one I'd remove. Either way, don't duplicate your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'ostruct'

class Hsh
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @arr = (0..9).map{ |i| OpenStruct.new(:one => i, :two => "#{i}")}
  end

  def each(&block)
    @arr.each(&block)
  end
end

p Hsh.new.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.one] = b.two; a} 
#=> {5=>"5", 0=>"0", 6=>"6", 1=>"1", 7=>"7", 2=>"2", 8=>"8", 3=>"3", 9=>"9", 4=>"4"}
```

In this particular case `Hsh` is actually an array, so unless you use it for something else such a complex code doesn't make sense, it can be done much easier:

```
p (0..9).map{ |i| OpenStruct.new(:one => i, :two => "#{i}")} \
  .inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.one] = b.two; a} 
#=> {5=>"5", 0=>"0", 6=>"6", 1=>"1", 7=>"7", 2=>"2", 8=>"8", 3=>"3", 9=>"9", 4=>"4"}
```

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't really need to implement it, just implement `Hsh#each`and include `Enumerable`, you'll get `inject` for free.

For your specific example something like this should work:

```
def inject accumulator
   #I assume Hsh has some way to iterate over the elements
   each do |elem|
    accumulator = yield accumulator, elem
   end
   accumulator
end
```

But the real implementation of inject is a bit different (e.g. works without providing an accumulator, takes a symbol instead of a block etc)

Comment: you mean like def each --- yield a --- yield b --- end?

Comment: yes, `#each` just needs to yield some values (in the case of an hash, you should do a `yield key, value` obviously, but you haven't told us how your class is implemented) to fit the `Enumerable` interface.

Comment: @antonpug more like `def each; @internal_array.each {|couple| yield(couple.one, couple.two)}; end`, defined in your `Hsh` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have used OpenStruct instead of classes. See if this works for you

```
require 'ostruct'

class Hsh
  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize
    obj = OpenStruct.new
    obj.one = 1
    obj.two = "two"
    @arr = [obj] 
  end

  def inject(hash)
    @arr.each do |arr|
      yield hash, arr
    end
    hash  
  end  
end

x = Hsh.new
p x.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.one] = b.two} #prints {1 => "two"}
```

---

Comment: Your method kind of works, but `inject` is supposed to pass the return value of a block to the first argument of the next iteration. That's why the OP returns `a` in the block.

Comment: yes.. but it depends on the implementation of `inject` method. I don't find the need for `a` to be returned for every iteration here.

Comment: I always find that mirroring a currently existing method while subtly changing the semantics will always come back and bite you in the future. IMHO @riffraff's answer is much better. This is the eternal dilemma between doing just what the OP wants and do the "right" thing.